# DEBIAN : apt-get update : Certificate verification error

Tags: debian, upgrade

I would like to upgrade my Debian 9 version.
Following this procedure : https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/uptodate.en.html

When I launch `apt-get update`, I get this errors :

```
Réception de:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian jessie InRelease [28,8 kB]
Réception de:3 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian buster InRelease [122 kB]
Ign:2 https://packages.dotdeb.org jessie InRelease
Err:1 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian jessie InRelease
  Les signatures suivantes ne sont pas valables : EXPKEYSIG 8C718D3B5072E1F5 MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
Ign:3 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Err:4 https://packages.dotdeb.org jessie Release
  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian jessie InRelease: Les signatures suivantes ne sont pas valables : EXPKEYSIG 8C718D3B5072E1F5 MySQL Release Engineering <mysql-build@oss.oracle.com>
W: Erreur de GPG : http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian buster InRelease : Les signatures suivantes n'ont pas pu être vérifiées car la clé publique n'est pas disponible : NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY DCC9EFBF77E11517
W: The repository 'http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian buster InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
root@colinweb:/# apt-get update
```

See the screenshot to have the colors :
[apt-get update errors screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIEos.png)

Here is my `/etc/apt/sources.list` content :

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib
```

I also tried to launch this command from this post https://askubuntu.com/questions/277793/getting-server-certificate-verification-failed-during-apt-get-update/277796#277796 :
`apt-get update -o Acquire::https::mirror.ufs.ac.za::Verify-Peer=false`

But I get the same error.

Comment: can you post the following `sudo apt-key list`

Comment: Too long to post the code, here is two screenshots.
https://ibb.co/8cWcJ92
https://ibb.co/GTcSfz6

Comment: I cannot open the screenshots, I get an empty file. In any case, I now see something strange that I haven´t notices before. You said Debian 9 but in the sources list you have two different distributions (Jessie -> Debian 8 and Buster -> Debian 10). What is the content of the /etc/debian_version file?

Comment: Also post the content of /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: I posted the screenshots as an answer so you can see it.
In my `/etc/debian_version` file I got this : `9.0`.
Only one line in my `/etc/apt/sources.list` : `deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib`,

Comment: See similar questions: https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+8C718D3B5072E1F5

Comment: @Beko I have added the sources.list file I am using. Try using the one I have provided you. Before backup the complete /etc/apt folder just in case and also comment other entries that you might have in the folder /etc/apt/sources.list.d. I can see you are using the Sury Package so you should also comment this one for now. If you update to Debian 10 and/or 11 you will not need this package any longer since PHP 7.4 is the default for these versions.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have an explanation of what needs to be done:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#repo-qg-apt-repo-manual-setup

Basically you need to run this command:

`apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8C718D3B5072E1F5`

For a Debian 9 you should have the following in your **/etc/apt/sources.list** file:

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
```

Comment: Got an error,
https://ibb.co/jkLJ434

Translation : 

`gpg: request for key 5072E1F5 on hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timeout expired
gpg: failed to receive from keyserver: keyserver error`

Comment: The command worked with this update : `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 8C718D3B5072E1F5` , but I got the same error after rewritng `apt-get update `

Answer (score 0):

I post the screenshot as an answer so you can see it.

[image: command result]
[image: command result 2]